# Do TVs from the UK work in the US

Tags: tv, international

I'm thinking about getting a TV while I live in the UK but I'm going to be moving back to the US eventually.   If I bring the TV back over will it work?

Comment: Per the FAQ, Super User is only for questions about computer hardware and computer software. http://superuser.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plug adapter would be needed unless it comes with one and the TV would need to operate at 100V. It also needs to be able to handle NTSC formats as that is the default in the US. It also needs to handle the 60Hz refresh rate; as the UK operates on 50Hz.

Most of these features should be part of any newer mid-range television however; it is always best to make sure.